# How to solve Base64DecodingException: It should be divisible by four error in java?

Tags: java

I was trying convert encoded String into decoded String in java. But i getting com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException: It should be divisible by four error. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The message is clear enough - a valid base64-encoded string is divisible by four.  Your input isn't, and thus it is **not** a correctly-encoded value.

There's nothing that can be done from the coding side to resolve this, you need to go back to the source (where the badly-encoded string was created) and get a correctly-encoded version.